# Objective-C throwing an exception in a static library. How can I catch the exception from a program using the library?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsexception

I am writing a static library with Cocoa and the Xcode project contains an "Example App" target. In the library, there are places in which I create an NSException object and raise it, with either the raise method or the @trow directive. I don't succeed to catch the exception in the example app. My code is:

```
 @try {
        sdk = [SDK GetInstanceWithApiKey:@"12345"];

    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception);
    }
```

Unfortunately, the application does not go to the catch block, it crashes normally like if I called the constructor without the try/catch block. Probably I am missing something important. Thanks

In the static library, this is the code I use to raise the exception:

```
NSException *exception = [[NSException alloc] initWithName:@"ConfigurationException" reason:@"Provided API Key is not valid." userInfo:NULL];

@throw exception;
```

This is the crash report in the log:

```
2018-02-24 19:11:38.504384+0100 Example App[6585:366375] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2018-02-24 19:11:38.504413+0100 Example App[6585:366375] [General] provided api key is not valid
2018-02-24 19:11:38.504475+0100 Example App[6585:366375] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e757fcb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff653f9c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Example App                         0x000000010000c701 -[raiseException:] + 273
    3   Example App                         0x0000000100005eff __84+[GetInstanceWithApiKey:sharedKey:productCode:licenseFilePath:]_block_invoke + 1567
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010032dd1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010032dcff dispatch_once_f + 288
    6   Example App                         0x0000000100005800 +[GetInstanceWithApiKey:sharedKey:productCode:licenseFilePath:] + 400
    7   Example App                         0x0000000100001b6b -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 91
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6e7bbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6e7aaa _CFXRegistrationPost + 442
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6e77f2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6a5670 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1664
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6a47a3 _CFXNotificationPost + 595
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff40789467 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bde760a -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 313
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bde7253 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 220
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bcb9f13 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 562
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bcb9b49 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 690
    18  Foundation                          0x00007fff407cc404 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 287
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff407cc282 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
    20  AE                                  0x00007fff3f7b7dd0 _Z20aeDispatchAppleEventPK6AEDescPS_jPh + 1788
    21  AE                                  0x00007fff3f7b7677 _ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS_ + 41
    22  AE                                  0x00007fff3f7b7565 aeProcessAppleEvent + 383
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3d9f95e0 AEProcessAppleEvent + 55
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bcb521e _DPSNextEvent + 2788
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff3c44ab4c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bca9d6d -[NSApplication run] + 764
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bc78f1a NSApplicationMain + 804
    28  Example App                         0x0000000100001b02 main + 34
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff65fe9115 start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
2018-02-24 19:11:38.505511+0100 Example App[6585:366375] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'LicenseConfigurationException', reason: 'provided api key is not valid'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e757fcb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff653f9c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Example App                         0x000000010000c701 -[raiseException:] + 273
    3   Example App                         0x0000000100005eff __84+[GetInstanceWithApiKey:sharedKey:productCode:licenseFilePath:]_block_invoke + 1567
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010032dd1f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010032dcff dispatch_once_f + 288
    6   Example App                         0x0000000100005800 +[GetInstanceWithApiKey:sharedKey:productCode:licenseFilePath:] + 400
    7   Example App                         0x0000000100001b6b -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 91
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6e7bbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6e7aaa _CFXRegistrationPost + 442
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6e77f2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6a5670 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1664
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3e6a47a3 _CFXNotificationPost + 595
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff40789467 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bde760a -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 313
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bde7253 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 220
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bcb9f13 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 562
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bcb9b49 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 690
    18  Foundation                          0x00007fff407cc404 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 287
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff407cc282 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
    20  AE                                  0x00007fff3f7b7dd0 _Z20aeDispatchAppleEventPK6AEDescPS_jPh + 1788
    21  AE                                  0x00007fff3f7b7677 _ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS_ + 41
    22  AE                                  0x00007fff3f7b7565 aeProcessAppleEvent + 383
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3d9f95e0 AEProcessAppleEvent + 55
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bcb521e _DPSNextEvent + 2788
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff3c44ab4c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bca9d6d -[NSApplication run] + 764
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff3bc78f1a NSApplicationMain + 804
    28  Example App                         0x0000000100001b02 main + 34
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff65fe9115 start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: plz show the relevant code  where you raise and thr stack trace you get.

Comment: What if you say `@catch(...)` instead?

Comment: Thanks Matt, unfortunately same result

Comment: Is the first snippet inside `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and is it the only instantiation in your code?

Comment: Yes, but now I tried to put it in a simple IBAction and the result is the same.

Comment: This works fine for me in a fresh project. I'd suggest working your way back to a minimal example. It must be something in the project settings.

Comment: Also, it's clear that the code you've provided doesn't actually correspond to the error you've posted (the exception class names are different, for one thing).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Found this on Apple -
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Check out "Listing 11" It states this:

> Note: If you find that exceptions thrown within an exception handling domain setup by your application are not being caught, verify that you are not specifying the -no_compact_unwind flag when building your application or libraries.

So you may need to remove that flag if it's in your build settings.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I already don't have this option in either the library or the example app